# php function error warning

Tags: php

My provious environment is php 5.2, now is php 5.3.
When I moved the website to new environment, it shows the error

The error warning is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng() in xx/application/libraries/crop2.php on line 537
```

and the error code is the ninth line in the following code:

```
protected function IM($file) 
{ 
    if(!file_exists($file)) die('File not exists.'); 
    $info = getimagesize($file); 
    switch($info['mime']) 
    { 
        case 'image/gif': 
        $mim = imagecreatefromgif($file); 
        break; 
        case 'image/png': 
        $mim = imagecreatefrompng($file); //  the error line 
        imagealphablending($mim, false); 
        imagesavealpha($mim, true); 
        break; 
        case 'image/jpeg': 
        $mim = imagecreatefromjpeg($file); 
        break; 
        default: 
        die('File format errors.'); 
    } 
    return $mim; 
}
```

How should I change it?

Comment: Apparently your new environment doesn't have PHP-GD installed or enabled.

Comment: `phpinfo()` and search for `GD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `phpinfo()` check whether you have `GD library for PHP installed`. Seems like it's missing.